# Drag and Drop uilabel or textfield from master view to detail view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

My question is how to enable drag and drop a uilabel from masterview to split view ,i don't use table view both of them are uiview ,i also need to create a copy of that label when you drag and drop it to the other view.